# Modifying a function involving CDFs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a function of several variables and I would like to modify it. My math background is somewhat limited when it comes to probability. The function is:

$$
p = \left ( \sum_{i=0}^{N} (G(i) - G(i-1))\cdot H(i-i)\right )^{K-1} 
$$
Where,
$$
G(x) = \left (F(x;N,\frac{1-t}{K})  \right )^{t} 
$$
$$
H(x) = \left (F(x;N,p+\frac{1-t}{K})  \right )^{t}
$$
and $F(x; a,b)$ is the CDF of the binomial distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$.

The functions as given calculate $p$ given fixed values of $N$, $K$ & $t$. But I want to get equations where $N$ is a function of $p$, and $K$ and $t$ are still fixed.

Is that even possible? Since $N$ terms are being summed up and $N$ is also used in the CDF. This exceeds my math ability so any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have a typo in $H(i-i)$ as this would give $H(i-i)=0$. I assume $N$ is an integer, what about $K$ and $t$? Also note that when typically one considers for the incomplete beta function that $x\in[0,1]$, in this case it is clearly not the case. I would've started with trying to find something for $G(i)-G(i-1)$ but as it is the upper limit of the integral that changes and not the powers inside the integral, there are at least as I know no recursive formulas to relate these two. If you are interested in some identities, try looking at e.g. https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.

Comment: @AxelT Thank you. No, the formula is correct. It is from a paper and they do indeed evaluate the CDF at -1 for the first term. I was just wondering if it is possible, but if it is not, that's fine. I am just doing a numerical approach of evaluation the formula as is and picking the points of p, K and T I want.